# How to find numbers out of a string/array with spaces in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string

EXAMPLE:
If I have this string/array: "123 45  6" (The numbers are separated by at least one space), how can I separate the numbers so I can use the numbers 123,45 and 6 separately?

I have know idea how to do it.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: man strtok https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok

Answer (score 2):

Try `strtol()` (prototype in `<stdlib.h>`)

```
char data[] = "123 45 6";
char *p = data;

while (*p) {
    long k = strtol(p, &p, 10);
    /* add error checking */
    printf("%ld\n", k);
}
```

Comment: When `data` is an unknown string, would suggest at minimum inclusion of `<errno.h>` and `errno = 0; long k = strtol(p, &p, 10); if (errno) {...handle error...}`. (of course that isn't necessary for the example given)

Comment: Yes @DavidCRankin, also maybe check if `*p` is whitespace or a digit ...

Comment: Yes, agreed, and possibly even a nested `while (*p && (*p < '0' || *p > '9')) p++;` after the `/* add error checking */` to scan forward for the next digit -- which would skip over any intervening non-digit characters if included. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Though I find the `strtol`-approach of png the most elegant way, let me also propose an approach utilising the `"%n"`-feature of `scanf`. This feature returns the number of characters scanned so far and can be used for pointing to the next portion to read in:

```
int main() {

    const char *data = "123 45 6  ";

    while (data && *data) { 
        int value=0;
        int index=0;
        if (sscanf(data,"%d%n",&value,&index) != 1)
            break;

        printf("%d\n", value);
        data+=index;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a function which will split your string in a double array of strings, using spaces as a delimiter.

The prototype of this function would be for example :

```
char **StrSplit(char *str, char c);
```

Then you would be able to call it in your code with str as the string you want to take the numbers from, and c as the space character (or any character used as a delimiter).

It would return a double array of strings containing in each entry a string for each number.

Then you would be able to convert each entry (containing a string of numbers) as an integer using the function atoi on it.